# Oracle and MS SQL Query very slow over VPN

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, networking, vpn

I have a C# program that uses the [Oracle Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) to an Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition 12.1.0.2.0 64bit. 
On the LAN a select within the Program takes about 2 seconds. If I establish a connection over a VPN tunnel the same select takes about 48 seconds.
If I ping the database:
LAN: 0.206 ms
VPN: 53 ms

Just to be sure I tested this also with the Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1 which shows about the same results.

I tried lowering the MTU to 1400 on the client side because some sites mentioned fragmentation as a cause of the problem but this didn't change anything at least in the way I configured it. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but are you connecting to the same database via LAN and then VPN?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: How large are your objects and how many are selected? This could be a bandwidth issue. Also, what VPN are you using? One you're hosting yourself in-house or a public/ commercial one?

Comment: Well I suppose there is no reason why the database would be using different execution plan... so before checking that, can you update your select on VPN so, that it won't return any rows? (add 1=0 after where clause). That way we can see if the time is lowered in case that the result is much smaller... Exactly as @MindSwipe mentions, seems like bandwidth issue on the first glance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by objects? I select 14 fields and the result has about 52K Rows. We use OpenVPN. My GUI Version is 11.10.0.0 the server is located in house. In the logs it says OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32; OpenSSL 1.1.0h
If I try selects with empty results: LAN: 0,001 seconds, VPN: 0,04 up to 0,09 seconds

Comment: From your question and comment, we see that your VPN is around 50 times slower than non-vpn connection, so you're lucky to go from 2 to 48 seconds, and not 100. To be sure, try to get session stats about network activity, it will tell you how much time it spent sending and waiting for data.

Comment: Network latency is compounded by the number of SQL*Net round trips required to process the query and fetch the data.  One way to minimize network latency is to ensure your array fetch size in the C# program is set to a high number.  Let's say for example it is 10, then you'll need 5, 200 network round-trips to return 52 thousand rows.  Whereas if it was set to 5,000, you'd need just over 11 network round-trips.

Comment: @RogerCornejo Thank you, this did help a lot. Please make an answer ou of your comment and I'll mark it as solution

Comment: @k4yaman Thank you for your note.  I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Network latency is compounded by the number of SQL*Net round trips required to process the query and fetch the data. One way to minimize network latency is to ensure your array [fetch size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/CommandFetchSize.htm) in the C# program is set to a high number. Let's say for example it is 10, then you'll need 5,200 network round-trips to return 52 thousand rows. Whereas if it was set to 5,000, you'd need just 11 network round-trips.

For MS SQL Databases the [Packet size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.packetsize?view=netframework-4.8) can be used in the connection string.